# How do I pass column-specific arguments to lapply in data.table .SD?

Tags: r, data.table, parameter-passing, lapply, mapply

I have seen examples of using `.SD`with `lapply` in `data.table` with a simple function as below:

```
DT[ , .(b,d,e) := lapply(.SD, tan), .SDcols = .(b,d,e)]
```

But I'm unsure of how to use column-specific arguments in a multiple argument function. For instance I have a `winsorize` function, I want to apply it to a subset of columns in a data table but using column-specific percentiles, e.g.

```
library(DescTools)
wlevel <- list(b=list(lower=0.01,upper=0.99), c=list(upper=0.02,upper=0.95))
DT[ , .(b,c) :=lapply(.SD, function(x) 
{winsorize(x,wlevel$zzz$lower,wlevel$zzz$upper)}), .SDcols = .(b,c)]
```

Where `zzz` will be the respective column to iterate. I have also seen threads on using changing arguments with `lapply` but not in the context of data table with `.SDcols`

Is this possible to do?

This is a toy example, looking to generalize for the case of arbitrary large number of columns; Looping is always an option but trying to see if there's a more elegant/efficient solution...

Comment: There is more than one `winsorize` in R packages. To make your code example reproducible you need `library(DescTools)`.

Comment: Also, better to use [list notation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html) for multiple columns: `DT[ , .(b,d,e) := lapply(.SD, tan), .SDcols = .(b,d,e)]`

Answer (score 1):

> ***How to use column-specific arguments in a multiple argument function?***

Use [`mapply(FUN, dat, params1, params2, ...)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mapply.html) where each of `params1, params2, ...` can be a list or vector; `mapply` iterates over each of `dat, params1, params2, ...` in parallel.

Note that unlike the rest of the `apply/lapply/sapply` family, with `mapply` the function argument comes first, then the data and parameter(s).

In your case (pseudo-code, you'll need to tweak it to get it to run) something like:

Instead of your nested list `wlevel  <- list(b=list(lower=0.01,upper=0.99), c=list(upper=0.02,upper=0.95))`, probably easier to unpack to:

```
w_lower <- list(b=0.01, c=0.02)
w_upper <- list(b=0.99, c=0.95) 

DT[ , c('b','c') := mapply(function(x, w_lower_col, w_upper_col) { winsorize(x, w_lower_col, w_upper_col) },
  .SD, w_lower, w_upper), .SDcols = c('b', 'c')]
```

We shouldn't need to use column-names (your `zzz`) in indexing into the list, `mapply()` should just iterate over the list as-is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @smci but is not working for me. I get warning messages: column matrix RHS of := will be treated as vector. Supplied 105866 items to be assigned to 52933 items of column 'b' (52933 unused). Any thoughts? Not sure why I am supplying 2x nrows

Comment: After further exploration, setting SIMPLIFY=F in mapply fixes the problem.